# Is there a recommended method of maintaining multiple Photos libraries on same hard drive

Tags: photos

My main Master Photos Library is over 400GB, and getting too big to tote around on trips.  I keep it on removable HD.  So I started creating new library for each trip.  Problem now is managing them all, and creating a master.  I use Power Photos (from Fat Cat) to move photos between libraries, but they don't support Live Photos.  A given trip might be as many as 4000 photos.  Some from SLR some from iPhone (Live Photo) and I combine them in the library.  Any suggestions on managing these and combining the libraries?

Comment: Photos is happy to have multiple folders. You'll want a third party tool to merge / move files back and forth. What does managing look like to you in specific terms?

Comment: Already use 3rd party Power Photos to move photos back and forth.  Doesn't move Live Photos, so end up with just jpeg.  Looking for something that can do both.  'Managing' my photos would enable me to create separate library for a trip, do edits, then easily merge into the master library when I get home.  The suggestion below to use Lightroom won't help either; no support for Live Photos.  Apple created a new format standard but didn't really provide for the ability to manipulate or combine very easily.  Have to go back and forth to the iPhone to move the Live Photos.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly Photos.app is not really designed as a pro or semi-pro photo managing application. It certainly seems to handle larger libraries better than iPhoto ever did but if you are taking that many pictures and want to manage them on your Mac you might want to consider an app designed specifically for the workflow and archiving of thousands of pictures.

Adobe has an app for that (Lightroom, I think it is called), and like many Adobe apps is the subject of much praise and anger online. Me, I just use photos.app because my needs are met with photos.app, but it sounds like you might be better served with something more capable than a consumer level photo managing app. IMHO